# How to deal elegantly with abstract factory and arrays as a return type in C++?

Tags: c++, covariance, abstract-factory

Having in mind the abstract factory pattern, imagine that you have a [class hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern#Structure) where concrete factories override a createButton**s** virtual method, needing to return a wider array of buttons. What could be an elegant workaround to resolve this, as C++ supports only covariant return types? dynamic_cast?

A modified version of GoF's example to fit my requirement:

```
class Button {
public:
        virtual void paint() = 0;
        virtual ~Button(){
        }
};

class WinButton: public Button {
public:
        void paint() {
                cout << "I'm a WinButton";
        }
};

class OSXButton: public Button {
public:
        void paint() {
                cout << "I'm an OSXButton";
        }
};

class GUIFactory {
public:
        virtual Button * createButtons() = 0;
        virtual ~GUIFactory(){
        }
};

class WinFactory: public GUIFactory {
public:
        WinButton* createButtons() {
                return new WinButton[2];
        }

        ~WinFactory(){
        }
};

class OSXFactory: public GUIFactory {
public:
        OSXButton* createButtons() {
                return new OSXButton[2];
        }

        ~OSXFactory(){
        }
};
```

And the application skeleton:

```
Application(GUIFactory * factory) {
                Button* buttons = factory->createButtons();
                for(...) {...}
        }
```

Comment: can you post some pseudo-code to demonstrate the expected behaviour? (does not need to compile, of course)

Comment: Not much details in there. How is a `button` declared? What do you mean with createButton*s* - that there are 2 functions or 1? What is it that you realy ask - what the function should return?

Comment: I do want! What do you mean? :)

Comment: Of course in my code I don't program a UI framework, but I thought it would be better to provide an example via the known windowing example.

Comment: @AggelosBiboudis: for the record, I nuked my answer, because indeed it didn't _work_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be done. Ask yourself, will the caller `delete` or `delete[]` it? How will they know how many elements are in the arrays? There's no way to solve either of these problems with a raw pointer return. So the simple answer to your question is that this cannot be done, nor should you even want to. The callee *needs to know* the return type- whether it's one button or many, and how to clean them up when he's done.

You can't even *access* the non-first element without invoking Undefined Behaviour.

A Factory is supposed to construct individual objects. If you need more than one, call the factory function more than once.

Even if you magically had code that could deal with more than one button at once when they were expecting just one (wtf?), you need to safely return more than one. That means `std::vector<smart_pointer<Button>>`.

Comment: I recognized that from the first time. Maybe I shouldn't have used the term "array" in the title. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

You **do not** want to create an array in the factory method and return a pointer to the client. That way you have **no** idea how many buttons there are, so you really cannot do anything with what you get.

In C++11 you can return a `std::vector<shared_ptr<Button>>` or even a `std::vector<unique_ptr<Button>>`.

I would probably opt for this solution though: Return some sort of a custom "readonly" `Button` collection that exposes the count and an indexer and nothing more. Maybe add iterators, if that'd suit your scenarios.

```
class ButtonCollection
{
public:
    size_t getCount() const {}
    Button& getAt(size_t index) {}
    const Button& getAt(size_t index) const {}

private:
    friend class GUIFactory;

    ButtonCollection() {}
    add(Button* button) {}
    // Or in C++11:
    // add(std::unique_ptr<Button> button) {}
};
```

With your application skeleton:

```
Application(GUIFactory& factory)
{
   std::auto_ptr<ButtonCollection> buttons = factory.createButtons();
   // Or in C++11:
   //std::unique_ptr<ButtonCollection> buttons = factory.createButtons();
   for(...) {...}
}
```

Comment: I took it the OP understands that, but rather wanted to address the technical point of covariance, only. The sample as such is contrived. I don't recommend C arrays or return raw pointers, but in the course of _learning the language_ it is pretty valuable to use the basics!

Comment: The code was rather childish, I wanted to craft a quick example to demonstrate my question, about an elegant way on this issue (not why this happens ;)). Furthermore it is a real time application (nothing to do with UI), thus I thought that playing with pointers and references is good enough for my case! Thank you both for your answers.

Comment: However if I return a vector<Derived> and the client wants just vector<Base> don't I want a way to reinterpret my data?

Comment: @AggelosBiboudis: If you find yourself needing concrete `Derived` instead of `Base`, then you're (likely) not using your polymorphic types polymorphically. The only place where you (in exceptional circumstances) should want that is where you already *know* that the actual `Base` *is a* `Derived`. How often does that happen? Yes, you *can* use `dynamic_cast<>` to get the concrete type, but that's more often than not a design smell.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `boost::ptr_vector` or `boost::ptr_array`
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html